# Topologies induced by Metrics

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, algebraic-topology

I wanted a proof of the fact that "Hamming Metric" induces a discrete topology on $ A^k$, where $A$ is a any set.

The hamming distance between two k- tuplets  $ (a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_k)$ and $ (b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_k) $ is defined as:

The number of pairs $(a_i,b_i) $, such that $ a_i $ is different from $ b_i $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show a topology is discrete it suffices to show that singletons are open. In the case of this metric space, that consists of finding some *real number* $\epsilon$ for each point $x = (a_1, \dots, a_k)$ such that that open ball $B(x,\epsilon)$ contains only $x$ itself.

Answer (score 2):

Take any $x \in A^k$, and consider an open ball of radius $\frac{1}{2}$ around $x$ in the Hamming metric. It's clear that it consists only of a single point $x$. Therefore, $\{x \}$ is open, and so the topology is discrete.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: for any $\vec a$, what is 
$$
B_{\frac12}(a) = \{\vec b \in A^k \mid d(\vec a,\vec b) < \tfrac12\}?
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: try to prove the stronger statement that every finite metric space is discrete in the induced topology.